# How to display special characters in PHPFOX

Tags: php, html, phpfox

I have a phrase where I am not able to display single quote.
This phrase is used to send as subject to email and single quote is displayed in ASCII

The phrase is

```
{full_name} commented on {other_full_name}'s recipe.
```

Comment: As it's now, this question doesn't make any sense: we're in 2014, all decent apps use UTF-8 and ASCII is a subset of UTF-8. I see you initially wrote `"&#039;"` and edited it out. Do you mean that you are getting double-encoding, e.g., `&amp;#039;` in your HTML **source code**?

Comment: No actually its been encoded once as &#039; for a qoute.

Comment: If the phrase is {full_name} commented on {other_full_name}'s recipe, the email subject is encoded as abc commented on xyz&#039;s recipe.
Could you tell me how to display ' instead of ascii value?

Comment: Aren't we talking about [this character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/27/index.htm)? Isn't that correct HTML entity?

Comment: Yes, exactly. But i need to display apostrophe inplace of ASCII code